# File descriptor duplication behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptors

I have this file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

When I run `paste` in this manner

```
paste - - <file
```

this results

```
1       2
3       4
```

so far so good, standard input(redirected from `file`) is passed twice to `paste` therefore odd- and even-numbered lines print in pairs.

However, when this is changed to

```
paste - /dev/fd/0 <file
```

the output becomes

```
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
```

`paste` appears to be opening `file` twice (leading to two distinct entries in the kernel's file table?), once for the `-` argument and once again for `/dev/fd/0`.

I am at a loss to explain this - if I'm interpreting [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=15) correctly, both `-` and `/dev/fd/0` ought to be referencing a single kernel file table entry therefore `paste` should be yielding results identical to the previous case.

Comment: See also [How to overwrite stdout using echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/151367)

Comment: Or [OS X, bash: less works on open file descriptors, cat doesn't](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209620)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's specific to Linux. While on most Unices, opening `/dev/fd/n` is more or less the same as `dup(n)` (get a file descriptor to the same *open file description* as on fd `n`), on Linux, `/dev/fd/n` is a symlink to the file open on file descriptor `n`.

So, on Linux:

```
paste - /dev/fd/0 < file
```

is the same as:

```
paste - file < file
```

(or `paste file file`).

The two fds (0 for `-` and the own obtained by opening `/dev/fd/0` or `file`), are independent and have  their own cursor within the file.

You'll also notice that on Linux, you can't use /dev/fd/n with sockets.

Generally on Linux, you only want to use `/dev/fd/n` with pipes. But in this case

```
cat file | paste - /dev/fd/0
```

(or switching to a non-Linux-based OS) won't really help. `paste - -` works because `paste` knows it's stdin in both cases. But not here, so it will read a whole chunk (as opposed to a single line) from `-` (fd 0 to the pipe), and then another chunk from /dev/fd/0 (an independent fd to the same pipe on Linux, but whether those fds point to the same *open file description* or not doesn't matter for a pipe). Both `read()`s will read separate parts of the file, but several lines at a time.

You'd need to tell `paste` to read one byte at a time so it doesn't read more than one line from `-` before reading a line from `/dev/fd/0`, which you can probably not do without recompiling. You might be able to get `paste` to read its stdin one byte at a time with `stdbuf`, but probably not `/dev/fd/0`:

```
$ cat file | paste - /dev/fd/0
1
2
3
4
$ cat file | stdbuf -i1 paste - /dev/fd/0
1       2
        3
        4
```

Comment: Indeed - as borne out by the output from `{ ls -lart /proc/$BASHPID/fd/5 ; } <file 5<&0`. I'm baffled as to why `linux` should choose to implement `/dev/fd` in this manner

Comment: @iruvar, it has its uses. See [here](/q/296432), [there](/a/68253), [there](/a/57598), [there](/a/181996), [there](/a/288271)

Comment: It seams logical and correct to me. I can not get my head around the alternative. Think what would happen if you made a link to a file hard or soft, and fed them both into paste? It is just another directory entry to the same file, so should act as such.

Comment: @richard, in case your comment was directed at my original comment -now that it has come to light that `/dev/fd` is implemented using symlinks under linux, I have no issues with `paste` behaviour under `linux` whatsoever - however, I was asking why `linux` did things differently from other Unices in this regard. Stephane's links shed light on how this could be useful under some circumstances, so I'm all good